# Finding geology of a GPS location like in water or on a road

Tags: php, api, dictionary, gps, watermark

I am working on a project that I have array of GPS locations.
I want to know for each of those points, where are they?
I have a specific list that I am trying to match their location to one of those such as: Water, Highway, railway, ...
I tried this API (http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/geocoding-http-api/Documentation) but it doesn't give me any accurate data! even less than 50% correct!
Do you know any better solution?

- I use php for server side that is responsible to gathering data from different webservices.
  Our client sides are Android, Java
- I expect system search and find the type of location automaticall

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any hint of your platform (pc? smartphone? by hand?  In automated program?)

But as a great starting point working with a few points by hand, in maps.google.com if you put the latitude and longitude (may be longitude and latitude try both) it will show them to you on the map.  Google maps even has simple APIs so you can use this functionality reasonably simply (for example from a matlab program).

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mentioned. I use php on our server. We expect system automatically recognize the place. ps: I couldn't find any google API. As I searched, I found out that Google is terminating those APIs.